# Any reason why socket.send() hangs?

Tags: python, sockets, ftp

I'm writing an mini FTP server in Python that exposes an underlying database as if it was FTP.  The flow is something like this:

```
sock.send("150 Here's the file you wanted\r\n")
proc = Popen2(...)
for parts in data:
    data_sock.send(parts)
proc.kill()
sock.send("226 There's the file you wanted\r\n")
data_sock.shutdown(0)
data_sock.close()
```

data_sock is the PASV socket that's up and working, confirmed by Wireshark.  What's actually happening is after the 163,328th byte has been sent over the data_sock, the data_sock.send() line just hangs.  I suspect the send buffer is full, but it's a mystery to me why the FTP clients wouldn't be reading from the PASV socket.

I've included the Popen2(...) line because I've managed to reproduce http://bugs.python.org/issue3006 on OS X--sockets don't close until the Popen process is killed.  Not sure if this is somehow related.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say from this code fragment and not knowing the client, but is it possible that your sending of 150 (indicating a new data channel), not 125 (indicating use of existing data channel) confuses the client and it simply does not start reading the data?

Have you had a look of [pyftpdlib](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) as an alternative for rolling your own server?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issues on the client side on uploads, which seem to trace to the modem/router choking -- the only workround I have at the moment is to throttle the transmission rate (send 128 bytes, sleep ~50ms, repeat).

Comment: I'm testing with both ends on localhost.  Maybe this is wrong, but my mental model says that with nice priorities being equal, send/receive should be about the same speed, no?

Answer (score 0):

One reason a client could stop reading the data is that somebody unplugged the client (or disconnected its Ethernet cable) during the transfer.  In that case, TCP will keep (unsuccessfully) resending packets for several minutes, getting no response, until it gives up.  There are other possible reasons as well.

Since the above possibilities are something you'll have to deal with if you want a robust server, the real question is not necessarily why it happens but rather what you should do when it does happen.  Some possible things to do are:

1. Make sure the clients don't have any bugs that cause them to stop reading even though data is available
2. Make sure that the server doesn't block even if a particular connection's send() call does block (you can do this via select()/poll() and non-blocking sockets, or possibly via multithreading... I recommend the former if possible)
3. Add some timeout logic to select() so that if more than (N) seconds go by where a socket has data ready to send but isn't actually sending it, the server gives up and closes the socket.  (TCP does this itself, but TCP's timeout period may be too long for your taste)